# Persistent Privilige Violations in Console causing extreme OS delays

Tags: macos, partitioning, ntfs, boot-camp, exfat

I have a 27" iMac at home with Boot Camp running Windows 10 on a "standard" NTFS-formatted partition, in addition to an external hard drive running a GUID partition scheme with an exFAT partition and another hard drive that's running purely on NTFS.

For a very long time, I've had serious issues with the Mac side (10.11) of the iMac running extremely slow with persistent freezes, hangups, beachballs and the like. I know there's no hardware issue as I've done hard drive tests down to full reformats and repartitions. The bigger indicator is that the Windows 10 Boot Camp side runs smoothly. (I also have no I/O errors showing in console).

Console is constantly reporting "Kernel:  Privilege Violations" corresponding with the various Windows-based partitions, (disk0s2, disk2s1 and disk1s3) and right now, that's my only guess as to what could be causing the slowdown.

Now I do have CrashPlan running full backups of my system (including the Windows partitions), so that's likely why the Mac side is accessing the Windows partitions, but is there any way to prevent these "privilege violations?" I'm getting dozens of them a minute in random surges.

Any advice would be appreciated.